# Access docker localhost API from Android Emulator

Tags: android, docker, android-emulator

I'm attempting to test my local dockerised API against a staging version of my app.

I don't have access to the repository to build the App myself so I'm relying on changing the IP address within the emulator to point at my local machine and that's where I'm failing.

I've set it to 10.0.2.2 as per the emulator documentation, and when I ping the staging url from the ADB shell (ping mystagingsite.com) it responds data from 10.0.2.2 . But from within the app, the response is always empty. I've tried 127.0.0.1 which obviously won't work, and I've tried my network IP address.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? If it is, what is the right IP address to put in the /etc/hosts file of the emulator and how do I find that address?